# Simple communication USB with python PyUSB on Windows 10

Tags: python, windows-10, usb, pyusb

I'm trying to communicate with a USB device with python. I am running Windows 10 and that I use Python 3.7.2 32bit.
I installed PyUSB with pip

```
pip install pyusb
```

Here is my test code

```
import usb.core

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x1664, idProduct=0x0001)
if dev is None:
    raise ValueError('Device not found')
dev.set_configuration()
print("Read: ", dev.read(0x81, 7))
print("Write: ", dev.write(1, '0xB1'))
```

On my reading function or my writing function I have an error:

> usb.core.USBError: [Errno 5] Input/Output Error

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you running the code with admin priviledges ? Most of the times this error happens because your code has no elevated priviledges.

Comment: I just did the administrator test, it doesn't work I get the same error message.

Comment: What's the full traceback? Just showing the error doesn't tell us what part of the code is triggering it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution.
I used this software [zadig](https://zadig.akeo.ie/) to change the usb driver of my device from WinUSB to libusb-win32.

Now read write work perfectly.

Comment: what else did you do? I don't get it to run. see https://stackoverflow.com/q/59105167/7295599