# PyUSB: reading from a USB device (2)

Tags: python, windows, usb, libusb, pyusb

Unfortunately, again I am experiencing some problems with communication via USB with PyUSB under Windows. In my [question about 2-3 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59105167/7295599), the problem was that the vendor provided wrong documentation and wrong SCPI commands.

Now, I would like to communicate with a stepper-motor controller (TMCM-6110) from [Trinamic](https://www.trinamic.com/).
Everything works fine with the IDE from the vendor, but now I want to address the device via [pyusb](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/), starting again from this [pyusb-tutorial](https://github.com/pyusb/pyusb/blob/master/docs/tutorial.rst).

The device is found, so I assume:

- libusb is installed correctly and found
- idVendor and idProduct are correct

The commands I have to send are fixed 9 bytes messages.
For example: "move to position absolute motor0 12800 steps".
The byte sequence is: `b'\x01\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x32\x01\x39'` which, however, Python prints as `b'\x01\x04\x01\x00\x00\x002\x019'` which confused me and took me a while to figure out that this is the same.

From the output from `print(dev)`, I assume that the address is 3.
However, I get error messages:

**Script:**

```
import usb.core
import usb.util

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x2a3c, idProduct=0x0100)
if dev is None:
    raise ValueError('Device is not found')
# device is found :-)
print(dev)

cmd = b'\x01\x04\x01\x00\x00\x002\x019'
# cmd = b'\x01\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x32\x01\x39'

dev.write(3,cmd)
```

**Output:**

```
DEVICE ID 2a3c:0100 on Bus 001 Address 006 =================
 bLength                :   0x12 (18 bytes)
 bDescriptorType        :    0x1 Device
 bcdUSB                 :  0x110 USB 1.1
 bDeviceClass           :    0x2 Communications Device
 bDeviceSubClass        :    0x0
 bDeviceProtocol        :    0x0
 bMaxPacketSize0        :   0x40 (64 bytes)
 idVendor               : 0x2a3c
 idProduct              : 0x0100
 bcdDevice              : 0x2e01 Device 46.01
 iManufacturer          :    0x1 Error Accessing String
 iProduct               :    0x2 Error Accessing String
 iSerialNumber          :    0x3 Error Accessing String
 bNumConfigurations     :    0x1
  CONFIGURATION 1: 100 mA ==================================
   bLength              :    0x9 (9 bytes)
   bDescriptorType      :    0x2 Configuration
   wTotalLength         :   0x43 (67 bytes)
   bNumInterfaces       :    0x2
   bConfigurationValue  :    0x1
   iConfiguration       :    0x0
   bmAttributes         :   0xc0 Self Powered
   bMaxPower            :   0x32 (100 mA)
    INTERFACE 0: CDC Communication =========================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x0
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x1
     bInterfaceClass    :    0x2 CDC Communication
     bInterfaceSubClass :    0x2
     bInterfaceProtocol :    0x1
     iInterface         :    0x0
      ENDPOINT 0x82: Interrupt IN ==========================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x82 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x3 Interrupt
       wMaxPacketSize   :    0x8 (8 bytes)
       bInterval        :   0xff
    INTERFACE 1: CDC Data ==================================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x1
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x2
     bInterfaceClass    :    0xa CDC Data
     bInterfaceSubClass :    0x0
     bInterfaceProtocol :    0x0
     iInterface         :    0x0
      ENDPOINT 0x3: Bulk OUT ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :    0x3 OUT
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x0
      ENDPOINT 0x81: Bulk IN ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :   0x40 (64 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x0
```

**Error 1:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Tilman\Programs\Python37\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 223, in get_interface_and_endpoint
    return self._ep_info[endpoint_address]
KeyError: 3
```

**Error 2:**

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Trinamic.py", line 13, in <module>
    dev.write(3,cmd)
  File "C:\Test\Programs\Python37\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 940, in write
    intf, ep = self._ctx.setup_request(self, endpoint)
  File "C:\Test\Programs\Python37\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 102, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Test\Programs\Python37\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 215, in setup_request
    intf, ep = self.get_interface_and_endpoint(device, endpoint_address)
  File "C:\Test\Programs\Python37\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 102, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Test\Programs\Python37\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 225, in get_interface_and_endpoint
    for intf in self.get_active_configuration(device):
  File "C:\Test\Programs\Python37\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 102, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Test\Programs\Python37\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 236, in get_active_configuration
    self.managed_open()
  File "C:\Test\Programs\Python37\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 102, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Test\Programs\Python37\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 120, in managed_open
    self.handle = self.backend.open_device(self.dev)
  File "C:\Test\Programs\Python37\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 786, in open_device
    return _DeviceHandle(dev)
  File "C:\Test\Programs\Python37\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 643, in __init__
    _check(_lib.libusb_open(self.devid, byref(self.handle)))
  File "C:\Test\Programs\Python37\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 593, in _check
    raise NotImplementedError(_strerror(ret))
NotImplementedError: Operation not supported or unimplemented on this platform
```

**Questions:**

- Error 1: What does `KeyError: 3` mean? Is 3 the wrong address?
- Error 2: What does `"NotImplementedError: Operation not supported or unimplemented on this platform"` mean? How to fix?
- What else to check and try in order to find out what's going wrong here?

And why can't these communication examples, no matter which interface (RS232, RS458, USB, LAN, ... ) be complete and working right away?

Comment: Here is a lambda I've been using to display byte arrays, since I was also annoyed by Python mixing ASCII and escaped hex:

`lambda ba: ''.join([f'{b:02x}' for b in ba])`

Answer (score 1):

This is a USB CDC ACM device, so the best way to talk to it is to make sure it is creating a COM port entry in the "Ports (COM & LPT)" list in your Device Manager and then open that COM port using [pySerial](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

You could use libusb to talk to it if you write and sign an INF file that tells Windows to load a different driver for your device (i.e. WinUSB), but it is a lot of trouble.  Hardcoding endpoint numbers like that means your code will only work for this particular device.

Comment: thank you for this hint. I didn't know about "special" devices, I thought this is simply USB. And on another application I am successfully talking to another device via pysusb. Actually, in the meantime I found a module on github (pyTrinamic), probably from the manufacturer himself. This seems to work, although, again documentation seems to be partly wrong or not updated. As a back-backup... I could try pySerial. Thanks for the input. Nevertheless, I would be interested in learning why the above USB connection does not work.

Comment: Because your device is probably managed by the usbser.sys driver in Windows.  That driver is in charge of all the I/O done to the device.  libusb doesn't know how to talk to that driver and that driver doesn't support anything like the libusb API, it is more limited.