# PyUSB: communication with OWON Oscilloscope (2)

Tags: python, windows, usb, libusb, pyusb

After quite some hassle [talking to an OWON oscilloscope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59105167/7295599),
there are new problems during the installation on another PC.

The USB driver seems to be installed, at least that's what Windows10 makes me believe.

[image]

The software which can be downloaded from PeakTech's homepage (DS_Wave V2.2.2) doesn't seem to work.
When trying to connect the device remotely via that software it causes a "crash"/restart of the oscilloscope.

Anyway, I don't want to use their software but I would like to address the oscilloscope via pyUSB.

This little Python program is working on the first PC but not on the second PC.

```
### communicate with a Peaktech 1337 Oscilloscope (OWON)
import usb.core
import usb.util
from usb.backend import libusb1

def send(dev,cmd):
    # address taken from results of print(dev):   ENDPOINT 0x3: Bulk OUT
    dev.write(3,cmd+'\r')
    # address taken from results of print(dev):   ENDPOINT 0x81: Bulk IN
    result = (dev.read(0x81,10000,1000)).tobytes().decode('utf-8')[:-4]
    return result

back = libusb1.get_backend()
print(type(back))

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x5345, idProduct=0x1234, backend=back)
print(dev)
dev.set_configuration()

print(send(dev,"*IDN?"))
### end of script
```

**Result on PC1:** (Python 3.7.4)

```
<class 'NoneType'>

DEVICE ID 5345:1234 on Bus 000 Address 001 =================
 bLength                :   0x12 (18 bytes)
 bDescriptorType        :    0x1 Device
 bcdUSB                 :  0x200 USB 2.0
 bDeviceClass           :    0x0 Specified at interface
 bDeviceSubClass        :    0x0
 bDeviceProtocol        :    0x0
 bMaxPacketSize0        :   0x40 (64 bytes)
 idVendor               : 0x5345
 idProduct              : 0x1234
 bcdDevice              :  0x294 Device 2.94
 iManufacturer          :    0x1 System CPU
 iProduct               :    0x2 Oscilloscope
 iSerialNumber          :    0x3 SERIAL
 bNumConfigurations     :    0x1
  CONFIGURATION 1: 500 mA ==================================
   bLength              :    0x9 (9 bytes)
   bDescriptorType      :    0x2 Configuration
   wTotalLength         :   0x20 (32 bytes)
   bNumInterfaces       :    0x1
   bConfigurationValue  :    0x1
   iConfiguration       :    0x5 Bulk Data Configuration
   bmAttributes         :   0xc0 Self Powered
   bMaxPower            :   0xfa (500 mA)
    INTERFACE 0: Physical ==================================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x0
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x2
     bInterfaceClass    :    0x5 Physical
     bInterfaceSubClass :    0x6
     bInterfaceProtocol :   0x50
     iInterface         :    0x4 Bulk Data Interface
      ENDPOINT 0x81: Bulk IN ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :  0x200 (512 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x0
      ENDPOINT 0x3: Bulk OUT ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :    0x3 OUT
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :  0x200 (512 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x0

,P1337,1842237,V2.4.     # <--- that's the response I'm expecting after sending `*IDN?`
```

**Result on PC2:** (Python 3.10.7)

```
<class 'usb.backend.libusb1._LibUSB'>

DEVICE ID 5345:1234 on Bus 001 Address 049 =================
 bLength                :   0x12 (18 bytes)
 bDescriptorType        :    0x1 Device
 bcdUSB                 :  0x200 USB 2.0
 bDeviceClass           :    0x0 Specified at interface
 bDeviceSubClass        :    0x0
 bDeviceProtocol        :    0x0
 bMaxPacketSize0        :   0x40 (64 bytes)
 idVendor               : 0x5345
 idProduct              : 0x1234
 bcdDevice              :  0x294 Device 2.94
 iManufacturer          :    0x1 Error Accessing String
 iProduct               :    0x2 Error Accessing String
 iSerialNumber          :    0x3 Error Accessing String
 bNumConfigurations     :    0x1
  CONFIGURATION 1: 500 mA ==================================
   bLength              :    0x9 (9 bytes)
   bDescriptorType      :    0x2 Configuration
   wTotalLength         :   0x20 (32 bytes)
   bNumInterfaces       :    0x1
   bConfigurationValue  :    0x1
   iConfiguration       :    0x5 Error Accessing String
   bmAttributes         :   0xc0 Self Powered
   bMaxPower            :   0xfa (500 mA)
    INTERFACE 0: Physical ==================================
     bLength            :    0x9 (9 bytes)
     bDescriptorType    :    0x4 Interface
     bInterfaceNumber   :    0x0
     bAlternateSetting  :    0x0
     bNumEndpoints      :    0x2
     bInterfaceClass    :    0x5 Physical
     bInterfaceSubClass :    0x6
     bInterfaceProtocol :   0x50
     iInterface         :    0x4 Error Accessing String
      ENDPOINT 0x81: Bulk IN ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :   0x81 IN
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :  0x200 (512 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x0
      ENDPOINT 0x3: Bulk OUT ===============================
       bLength          :    0x7 (7 bytes)
       bDescriptorType  :    0x5 Endpoint
       bEndpointAddress :    0x3 OUT
       bmAttributes     :    0x2 Bulk
       wMaxPacketSize   :  0x200 (512 bytes)
       bInterval        :    0x0
       
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lab\Programs\Test\Test_PeakTech.py", line 18, in <module>
    dev.set_configuration()
  File "C:\Users\Lab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 915, in set_configuration
    self._ctx.managed_set_configuration(self, configuration)
  File "C:\Users\Lab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 158, in managed_set_configuration
    self.managed_open()
  File "C:\Users\Lab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Lab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 131, in managed_open
    self.handle = self.backend.open_device(self.dev)
  File "C:\Users\Lab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 804, in open_device
    return _DeviceHandle(dev)
  File "C:\Users\Lab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 652, in __init__
    _check(_lib.libusb_open(self.devid, byref(self.handle)))
  File "C:\Users\Lab\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb1.py", line 604, in _check
    raise USBError(_strerror(ret), ret, _libusb_errno[ret])
usb.core.USBError: [Errno 13] Access denied (insufficient permissions)
```

What is going wrong here? I'm out of ideas and wasting my time

- which access and why is it denied?
- do I have the wrong driver at the right location or the right driver at the wrong location?
- might this be an issue between Python 3.7.4 and 3.10.7 ?
- any other info required to find out what the actual problem is?

Thank you for any hints.

Comment: I'd probably use WinUSB instead of libusb0.sys to talk to the oscilloscope, since WinUSB is built into Windows (unless there is some specific feature of libusb0.sys that you need and WinUSB doesn't support it).  Both drivers are supported by pyUSB / libusb.  Also, I don't know why you are calling `set_configuration`, maybe just remove it?  Usually the device's own drivers set the configuration automatically.

Comment: @DavidGrayson thank you for your comment. I will try WinUSB, if I find out how to tell Python to use it instead. I used `set_configuration()` because it was in the example in the tutorial of the PyUSB homepage and on PC1 the script doesn't work without it.

Comment: In general, you have to make signed driver (e.g. INF file) to make Windows use WinUSB.  There is a program called Zadig that circumvents the usual driver signing protections and lets you use attach WinUSB to any device.

Comment: @DavidGrayson yes, during my search I also came across Zadig. To me, everything looks pretty complicated and confusing with all these different libusb files and versions. No plug&play as you would expect with USB.